# Required validator does not work with number

Tags: angular

When the input is empty, no error appear.

The reason is that the NumberValueAccessor selector match the input, and set the value of the Control to a number. If the entered string of the input does not match a number, the value is NaN. This is the case for the empty string.
But the required validator return a error only if the control value is blank (null or undefined) or is a empty string. This is not the case of any of these two conditions because the NumberValueAccessor set the value to the NaN number.

The required validator can not really verify the NaN value because it can appear for empty string, but also for string that are not a number (like 'aaa'). The problem is that the validator can not retrieve the entered string from the control variable.

Quoted from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6932

I am still facing this issue. Is there any solution in Angular2

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement your own `requiredNumber` directive to apply.

The only special thing about this is that it is explicitly looking for the uninitialized `null` that the `control.value` would be set to on a number input.

**required-number.validator.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, Validators, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

function validateRequiredNumberFactory() : ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    let isValid = !isNaN(control.value) && control.value !== null;
    console.log('isNaN: ' + isNaN(control.value));

    if(isValid) {
      return null;
    }
    return { numberIsRequired: true };
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[requiredNumber][ngModel]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: RequiredNumberValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class RequiredNumberValidatorDirective implements Validator, OnChanges {
  private valFn = Validators.nullValidator;

  constructor() {
    this.valFn = validateRequiredNumberFactory();
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    return this.valFn(control);
  }
}
```

The input is thus:

```
<input requiredNumber name="someName" [(ngModel)]="myProperty" #namedInput="ngModel"/>
```

Here's a plunker where you can tweak to your liking http://plnkr.co/edit/gxTxOQBg8ilFHzgq4Ly0

Credit where it's due, this answer was derived from: http://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-template-driven-form-validators/

as I primarily utilize Reactive Forms with my validators all in code and outside of the template.